# Drilling down in graphs to see individual processes

Tags: linux, process, munin, graph

Are there any system monitoring tools like Munino or Observium, where you can drill down in a graph to see individual processes?

Like say if there's a graph of CPU usage, is it possible to click on the graph and then see which processes were taking up what percentage of CPU at any given time in the graph?

Answer (score 0):

The Command Line Interface (CLI) tool that does what you need and comes with most Linux distros is called Top, you can find a full breakdown of the tool here:
https://www.booleanworld.com/guide-linux-top-command/

There is also htop, a prettier version that contains some slightly different info.

A Graphical User Interface (GUI) tool that does what you want is:
https://www.monitorix.org/features.html

The link below contains two lists, the first is for CLI tools and the second for GUI based applications:
http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/06/list-of-best-system-monitoring.html